# CPU cache friendly byte slice

Tags: go, data-structures

I have a logger that writes a lot of messages in parallel to stdout. The problem is that messages were written simultaneously and shuffled.
So I had to add a mutex and lock before printing:

```
l.mu.Lock()
fmt.Fprintf(os.Stdout format, v...)
l.mu.Unlock()
```

I wish to avoid the locking because I need as small latency as possible. But I'm fine with some pauses and I don't care much about order of messages.
On my server I have 24 CPUs and each has it's own cache. I have an idea to make per-cpu list of byte slices and then periodically gather all of them and dump to a log.
Will this work in practice?
I'm feeling that I'm reinventing some existing structure.
Could you please recommend an optimal way to do that.

Comment: You can have one writer goroutine that reads the messages from a channel that is being written by multiple goroutines. You wouldn't need a mutex then.

Comment: Even a channel has some concurrency overhead. You could have a per-go routine log buffer that buffers X messages before sending them on a channel to a central logger (or before using a lock / printing to stdout, or whatever) to optimise the trade-off between throughput, memory use,  and possibly lost log messages when the application crashes.

Comment: So I need a contention free struct or something like thread local. I found a good article on the topic https://puzpuzpuz.dev/thread-local-state-in-go-huh and a library from the author https://github.com/puzpuzpuz/xsync
Nothing that I can start using but at least something

Comment: Asked a question directly https://github.com/puzpuzpuz/xsync/issues/90

Answer (score 1):

As with many concurrency problems I'd use a concurrent queue to solve this problem.

https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/antigloss/go/concurrent/container/queue seems to  be the kind of data structure that you could use to solve your problem.